# One Field mapping with multiple filelds : MsAccess SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am failing to combine *Team-Table* with *Matches-Table*, so that I can get statistics of team performance **year-wise**.

**Database Schema**

[image]

**Output required**

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question with attempted SQL code. Then, describe you issues or post any errors.

Comment: Just as a basic check does `SELECT * FROM matches JOIN teams ON (matches.HomeTeam=Team.id OR matches.AwayTeam=Team.id)` join?

Comment: Your team table should have a column team_id and match table should have the same column team_id as a foreign key reference. Only then you can establish a logical relation between two tables.

Comment: Are statistics in record for the Home team? Have you tried a CROSSTAB query? Edit question to show sample raw data. If saving team name in Matches, Teams table is not needed in query. Field name should be Team not Teams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the table relationship you have created. it is not useful. What you need is something this:

```
SELECT Teams.[TeamNameField], Year([Date]) AS MatchYear, [HomeYellowCardField] AS YellowCards FROM Matches INNER JOIN Teams ON Matches.HomeTeam=Teams.[TeamIDField]
UNION ALL
SELECT Teams.[TeamNameField], Year([Date]) AS MatchYear, [AwayYellowCardField] AS YellowCards FROM Matches INNER JOIN Teams ON Matches.AwayTeam=Teams.[TeamIDField]
```

Save that as a permanent query. With that as a starting point it should be much easier to get to your end goal.